# Python - Parse a String into Float Array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string as follows:

```
>>> a
'0 911 872.9 354.9 901.9 395.0 904.6 414.0 903.8 400.5'
```

Now I wish to convert it into an array:

```
>>> b
array([   0. ,  911. ,  872.9,  354.9,  901.9,  395. ,  904.6,  414. ,
        903.8,  400.5])
```

**What is the most Pythonic way of doing this?**

Comment: @BurhadKhalid: Are you sure, OP meant `numpy` and not [array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.fromstring(a, dtype=float, sep=' ')
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> np.fromstring('0 911 872.9 354.9 901.9 395.0 904.6 414.0 903.8 400.5', dtype=float, sep=' ')
array([   0. ,  911. ,  872.9,  354.9,  901.9,  395. ,  904.6,  414. ,  903.8,  400.5])
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would be to split the string based on white-space followed by mapping the string data to float. You can use imap, if you would not want to create throw away intermediate strings. Also I would suggest to create array's of doubles to reduce precision errors.

**Demo**

```
>>> from array import array
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> array('d', imap(float, a.split()))
array('d', [0.0, 911.0, 872.9, 354.9, 901.9, 395.0, 904.6, 414.0, 903.8, 400.5])
>>>
```

Comment: The difference in the representation of the resulting array indicates to me that the OP probably means numpy arrays. This is a useful answer too though.

Answer (score 3):

`b = array([float(x) for x in a.split()])`

Answer (score 0):

```
b = map(lambda x: float(x), x.split())
```